Use Hibernate to verify Java enum matches Postgres enum
The same values, in the same order.
This isn't hard to put into a unit test
final var queryString = 
  "SELECT unnest(enum_range(CAST(NULL AS %s))) AS v".formatted(dbName);
final var query = session.createNativeQuery(queryString, String.class);
final var dataList = query.getResultList();
Assertions.assertEquals(javaList, dataList);

It's also possible to get the list from the database using the information schema, so it should be available when the Session is being constructed. That means, it should be possible to use an Annotation that will do the same thing, without relying on unit tests. But I have little idea how to do this… Any ideas?
EDIT: So, to explain more thoroughly, I would like an annotation that causes the Session Factory build to error out, as it would if you specified a non-existent column in a @Column(name="fake") annotation or some other mismatch between the annotations and the existing database.

Can you clarify what exactly you want those annotation to do?

@talex I have edited the original question.

Create a Custom Annotation then Create a Validator after that Integrate Validator with Hibernate.

@BobSmith Is that done at session build?

@AndrewLazarus it was difficult to explain it in comment so posted as answer below, please take a look.

Actually Hibernate has a possibility to check if Java enums match PostgreSQL enums at the start of the session. In this case, a special annotation is added beside the fields that must be validated; a validator operates on basis of the fields added. In case they don’t, the application is not started, and thereby, inconsistency is prevented.

As told in the comment previously
Below are the steps to achieve it :
Step 1: Create a Custom Annotation
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidatePostgresEnum {
    String dbName();
}

Step 2: Create a Validator
import org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataContributor;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor;
import org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceRegistryImplementor;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryBuilderFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryBuilderImplementor;
import org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class PostgresEnumValidator implements MetadataContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(Metadata metadata, ServiceRegistryImplementor serviceRegistry) {
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder srb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder(serviceRegistry);
        SessionFactoryBuilderImplementor sessionFactoryBuilder = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder();
        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = (SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
        
        for (Class<?> entityClass : metadata.getEntityBindings().stream()
                .map(persistentClass -> persistentClass.getMappedClass())
                .collect(Collectors.toList())) {
            for (Field field : entityClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
                if (field.isAnnotationPresent(ValidatePostgresEnum.class)) {
                    ValidatePostgresEnum annotation = field.getAnnotation(ValidatePostgresEnum.class);
                    String dbName = annotation.dbName();
                    Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass = (Class<? extends Enum<?>>) field.getType();

                    List<String> javaEnumValues = Stream.of(enumClass.getEnumConstants())
                            .map(Enum::name)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

                    String queryString = String.format("SELECT unnest(enum_range(NULL::%s))", dbName);
                    List<String> dbEnumValues = sessionFactory.openSession().createNativeQuery(queryString, String.class).list();

                    if (!javaEnumValues.equals(dbEnumValues)) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Mismatch between Java enum and PostgreSQL enum values for " + dbName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Step 3: Integrate Validator with Hibernate
Configure Hibernate to use this validator during the session factory initialization.
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataImplementor;
import org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataSourcesContributor;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    public static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySetting("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate")
                .build();

        MetadataImplementor metadata = (MetadataImplementor) new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry)
                .addAnnotatedClass(MyEntity.class) // Add your entity classes here
                .getMetadataBuilder()
                .applyMetadataContributor(new PostgresEnumValidator())
                .build();

        return metadata.buildSessionFactory();
    }
}

Reference links :

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html

https://adeogooladipo.medium.com/hibernate-6-deep-dive-handling-enums-in-postgresql-398fc4b89608

Hibernate mapping between PostgreSQL enum and Java enum


